# Reusing functionality in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I created a page on which there's a red square that can be moved by a mouse.  I would like to find out how I can reuse Javascript to have more than 1 square.  In the following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sbel/utM5k/ I show that in HTML on top I include the CSS, the square is a div and the Javascript has the form (function(window) {...})(window);. How can I change the Javascript to be able to simply say here is the ID of a div, apply the moving functionality to it?

Comment: Note also that it's typical to wait for a few answers, assess their usefulness (usually considering votes from the community), and finally accept the "correct" answer after a few days have passed.  This strategy typically allows for better answers since many people do not view answered questions assuming they are complete =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than wrapping your functionality (variables and functions) in an anonymous closure (which is a good idea to avoid cluttering the global namespace), instead wrap them in a "class" definition so you can create multiple instances of your new type.

For example (not tested):

```javascript
function MovableItem(id) {
  this.element = document.getElementById(id);
  this.mouseIsDownOnMovable = false;
  this.layerX = 0;
  this.layerY = 0;
  this.movableHeight = this.element.getBoundingClientRect().height;
  this.movableWidth = this.element.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  // And so on for each "member" variable...
}

MovableItem.prototype.markThatMouseIsDownOnMovable = function(event) {
  this.mouseIsDownOnMovable = true;
  this.layerX = event.layerX;
  this.layerY = event.layerY;
}

MovableItem.prototype.markThatMouseIsUp = function() {
  this.mouseIsDownOnMovable = false;
}

// And so on for each "method"...
```

This refactoring will take some time as you will be learning some new concepts (especially regarding the use of the "this" variable) but when complete you will be able to have any number of your movable objects as such:

```javascript
var o1 = new MovableItem('slavaMovable');
var o2 = new MovableItem('slavaMovable2');
// ...
```

This is the general way to achieve object oriented reusability in JavaScript (though the implementation specifics may vary greatly depending on your ideological preferences).